# QL code in C++ program

Tags: c++, quantlib

I want to include the QuantLib function for option greeks calculations in my own C++ code. my question is can I just include those functions...I don't want to use the rest of their stuff. I obviously cannot just write

```
QuantLib::europeanOption.delta()
```

I have included the header

```
#include <ql/quantlib.hpp> using namespace QuantLib;
```

I wish they had some good documentation.

Answer (score 0):

How at ease are you with programming, dynamic linking, Makefiles and the rest?

In essence, there is no magic here. QL has a very liberal license, and you "merely" have to set up your project such that it finds

- the quantlib headers (and hence Boost headers) during compilation
- the quantlib library during linking

and both of those can be automated by calling `quantlib-config` with proper flags `--clags` and `--libs`, respectively.

This is *really* no different than linking to any other external library.